# NodeJS loading new images in gallery from Api (interval)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am fairly new to Node.js, coming from PHP it is quite different. I just want to know if i am taking the right approach for my project.

I created a simple Api to retrieve a list of local images on the computer and return the list as JSON. The ultimate goal is to upload the local images to a remote server from the local image gallery.

I am creating a simple image gallery right now. I can see and retrieve the list of photos trough the Api with the following function:

```
module.exports = {
index: (req, res) => {    
    request('http://localhost:4000/listPhotos', function (err, response, body) {
        if(err) {
            res.render('index', {response: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
        } else if(response.statusCode != 200) {
            res.render('index', {response: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
        } else {
            let jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body)
            if(jsonResponse == '' || jsonResponse == undefined || jsonResponse.length == 0) {
                res.render('index', {response: null, error: 'Error, please try again'});
            } else {
                console.log(jsonResponse);
                res.render('index', {photos: jsonResponse, error: null});
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

So it works and i can see new images as i refresh the page but how do i update the gallery without refreshing the page using Node.js? I tried building an interval around the function but then it gives me an error that the headers are already sent.

My question is, is this really the right approach? Do i have to use Node.js code for my front-end gallery or can i just use (for example: jQuery) with Api urls (which i am familiar with).

Answer (score 0):

I think streaming the content is what you need. That also depends on how you display the images. How do you trigger this function?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I use a Express Router on '/' that triggers this. Like this: routes.get('/', controller.index);

Comment: Are you uploading images to the server or retrieving images from the server actually?

Comment: I am scanning a local folder for new images and want to upload them to a remote server using the image gallery.

Comment: In the case you should be able to render the uploaded images from your page for the upload process needs to have the capability to tell you which files the server has received.

Answer (score 0):

there is to approaches,
Both Approaches are using XHR Requests so you won`t need to render the data when the user ask for the page an you can do that asynchronously.

First you can open a websocket from you server to the client and let him know when you got a new msg, when he`s getting a new msg on the websocket he will query for photos and you will send him the whole list (he will delete everything and put the new one). its a modern approach

There is another approach that the client can "update" his gallery from time to time (he will send an ajax request in defined interval)